# Multi step form with click and state logging in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, forms

I need to create two separate forms flows. Essentially the one case has 3 pages (intro, questions, thank you), while the other has 4 pages (intro, questions, questions, thank you). I want to be able to:

- Log the states of each "step" as the user proceeds
- Keep track of where the user clicks and in what sequence

I am thinking of doing the second part with Google Analytics, as I know it has ways to do this. However, I am not sure what is the best way to go with the multi step form process.

So far it sounds like I would have to create content types for each step and use rules to "guide" the user as he creates the different content types. However, this sounds like a nightmare when it comes to "back" and 'next" functions.

Can anyone please tell me what is the best way to implement a form like this, keeping in mind how important it is that the logging works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to follow copy and modify [this solution](https://github.com/davidsonjames/drupal-7-multistep-form). It allowed me to basically create a way by which I can just add a new "survey-2.php" file, which contains the brains of the various surveys I want to do. The ordering and persistence and all that stuff happens in the main module.

Answer (score 2):

I can't say that this is the best way, but you can achieve that using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

You can create multi step form using Webform module. Add *`Page break`* type to form components to split the form.

[image]

In Advanced Form Settings you can manage the multi step form actions like 'Automatically save as draft between pages and when there are validation errors' options.
[image]

In you want to provide advanced navigation bar for multi step web from you can try the [Webform steps](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_steps) module

> This module provides a navigation bar for multi-page webforms. The navigation bar is a set of buttons placed at the top of each webform page. The buttons allow free navigation between steps that have already been visited.

Answer (score 1):

From a sitebuilder's perspective, look at MSNF module with the Conditional Fields module. Doing this programmatically beats the hell out of anything else. Ctools Multipart, Multistep forms is the best that I have come across to do want you are looking for. Have a look at [Paul Booker's tutorial](http://www.paulbooker.co.uk/drupal-developer/code-snippet/building-multistep-registration-form-drupal-7-using-ctools) for a starter.

Comment: I think you are right. I've ended up reverse engineering this: https://github.com/davidsonjames/drupal-7-multistep-form ...

Answer (score -1):

I've written a tutorial about how multi step forms in Drupal works. You can read the tutorial on http://brattland.no/blog/drupal/multistep-forms-in-drupal-7

Comment: Hi @sbrattla, access to the site is blocked, it has been a link only answer before (which would count as NAA), please take the content over here.